# How do I write Functor and Applicative for Vector-Composition?

Tags: vector, functor, idris, dependent-type, applicative

I´m trying to learn more about dependent types using IDRIS.
The example I am trying to emulate uses composition of Vectors.
I understand Functor and Applicative implementations for Vectors but I am struggling to implement them for the Composition.

```
data Vector : Nat -> Type -> Type where
    Nil : Vector Z a
    (::) : a -> Vector n a -> Vector (S n) a

Functor (Vector n) where
    map f [] = []
    map f (x::xs) = f x :: map f xs

Applicative (Vector n) where
    pure = replicate _
    fs <*> vs = zipWith apply fs vs
```

Now the Composition and Decomposition-Function look like this:

```
data (:++) : (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> Type where
    Comp : (f . g) x -> (f :++ g) x

unComp : (f :++ g) a -> (f . g) a
unComp (Comp a) = a
```

User with Vectors it encapsulates a Vector of Vectors.
Now I need an Applicative for the Composition `(Vector n) :++ (Vector n)`.
I can´t even get Functor to work and am mainly trying to see what I´m doing wrong. I tried the following and, since Functor is already implemented for Vectors, that this would work

```
Functor ((Vector n) :++ (Vector n)) where
    map f (Comp [])        = Comp []
    map f (Comp (x::xs))   = Comp ((f x) :: (map f (Comp xs)))
```

but the Compiler gives an Error-Message:

```
When checking an application of constructor Main.:::
        Unifying a and Vector (S n) a would lead to infinite value
```

Isn´t unifying and element of `type a` and a `Vector n a` exactly the purpose of `(::)`?
I am obviously doing something wrong and I can´t get this to work. I also have the feeling it´s probably easy to solve, but after hours of reading and trying I still don´t get it.
If someone could give me advice or explain to me how the Functor and Applicative implementations could look like, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Idris 2 now has this builtin. [Functor for Compose](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/b8aaaf32759bc9f410058772901a0d6b98e881af/libs/prelude/Prelude/Interfaces.idr#L108-L112), [Applicative for Compose](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/b8aaaf32759bc9f410058772901a0d6b98e881af/libs/prelude/Prelude/Interfaces.idr#L166-L173)

I think you can implement a general instance of `Functor` and `Applicative` like with [Haskell's Compose](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Compose.html#Compose).

```hs
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) x)
    a <$ (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (a <$) x)

instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
    pure x = Compose (pure (pure x))
    Compose f <*> Compose x = Compose (liftA2 (<*>) f x)
    liftA2 f (Compose x) (Compose y) =
      Compose (liftA2 (liftA2 f) x y)
```

To answer your specific question (but don't do it this way):

```hs
Functor ((Vector n) :++ (Vector n)) where
    map f (Comp x) = Comp $ map (map f) x
```